# Multiple commands on a single line in cron

Tags: bash, shell, cron

Basically, I'm trying to run this beauty: `su pi -c "crontab -l | { cat; echo \"0 4 * * * pkill -f awesomeFile.py ; python /home/user/python/awesomeFile.py &\"; } | crontab -"`

I want to restart a python server every night at 4am.
This installs the cron job correctly, but the command doesn't execute correctly. It'll kill the old process, but won't start a new one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can try: `echo \"0 4 * * * $(pkill -f awesomeFile.py && python /home/user/python/awesomeFile.py) &\";` though it would be easier to call a python script that'll execute both commands ;)

Comment: Why are you trying to modify your crontab, when all you want to do is restart your server?? Just put an entry in your crontab: `0 4 * * * pkill -f awesomeFile.py && python /home/user/python/awesomeFile.py`. Dont make crontab modify itself as a part of cronjob.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. This is a line in a script that sets up the crontab. I only need it to run once. I want the cron entry to be `0 4 * * * pkill -f awesomeFile.py ; python /home/user/python/awesomeFile.py &` but I can't get that to work either.

Comment: Have you tried the solution that @alfasin suggested above?

Comment: @alfasin I tried that, but it gave me the same results. It's also not ideal in my situation because awesomeFile.py maybe have crashed. If so, I still want it to restart. With the logical AND, if the pkill doesn't kill anything, it'll return 1, then anything after the && won't run.

And now after typing that all out on my phone, I realize that you put it in a $(). I'll give that a shot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe cron does not know where `python` is. Try to run it with an absolute path.
With the `which` command you can get the location of python:

`$> which python
/usr/bin/python`

Answer (score 0):

I hate to comment on a dead thread but I just came across this exact issue and maybe it's because your pkill is returns without checking that the processes are dead.  Tack on that -w tag and it'll check back once per second to see if the kill was successful, then return.  For future users who are reliant on closing whatever's using their ports, make sure you wait until the prev process is dead before attempting the new one.